# error on page ($.plot is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, flot

I'm working on a webpage based on a template downloaded from the internet. This page contains several includes and I do not know enough to change.

My problem is that I am implementing a Flot chart and the error "Uncaught TypeError: $.plot is not a function" always occour.

I've implemented the same chart on a sample page and it works with four includes: jquery-2.2.3.min.js, /jquery.flot.min.js, jquery.flot.time.js, and utilitarios.js (my authorship )

I'm think that the problem may be in some include that is in the template and is in some type of conflict.

Line of erro:

```
$.plot("#line-chart", [line_data1, line_data2],
```

My Html source page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Painel Predial</title>

  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">


  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">


  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">


  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/morris/morris.css">


  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">


  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">


  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">


  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/iCheck/all.css">


  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css">


 <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">



 <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">


  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <!-- some informations -->
  </header>


  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">

<style>
.esconde{
 display:none;
}

</style>

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header">

  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/sistema/public"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
  </ol>
</section>

<section class="content">
  <!-- Área do form -->
  <form id="formDashboard">
  <div class="row esconde" id="boxForm">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Informe os critérios para geração do gráfico</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <!--Seleção de unidades -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Informe a macrolocalidade</label>
                <select id="macroLocalidadeSelect" class="form-control">
                  <option value=" ">Selecione...</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Informe a localidade</label>
                <select id="localidadeSelect" class="form-control">
                  <option value=" ">Selecione...</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Informe a unidade</label>
                <select id="unidadeSelect" class="form-control">
                  <option value=" ">Selecione...</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Informe o período desejado</label>
                <select id="periodo" class="form-control">
                  <option value="0">Registro Diário</option>
                  <option value="1">Media por Hora</option>
                  <option value="7">7 dias</option>
                  <option value="15">15 dias</option>
                  <option value="30">30 dias</option>
                  <option value="45">45 dias</option>
                  <option value="60">60 dias</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4" id='boxDataDia'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Informe a data que deseja consultar</label>

                <div class="input-group date">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="diaPesquisa" name="data_hora_inicio">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--
            <div class="col-xs-5">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label>Date:</label>
              <div class="input-group date">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker2" name="data_hora_fim">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-footer">
        <input type="hidden" value="5a5D0Rl5Vl57U4pesspDGe0lIhzTsXwNflDzidMb" name="_token">        
        <input type="button" onclick='processar()' class="btn btn-primary active" value="Gerar Relatório" />
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Limpar" />         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

<!-- Área do Gráfico -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
    <!-- Área de mensagem de erro -->
    <div class="box box-danger box-solid esconde" id="boxError">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Erro</h3>

      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-tools -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body" id="boxErrorMessage">

    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.box -->



  <!--Área de mensagem -->
  <div class="box box-primary box-solid esconde" id="boxAguarde">
    <div class="box-header">
      <h3 class="box-title">Carregando....</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
      Aguarde enquanto o gráfico é gerado
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <!-- Loading (remove the following to stop the loading)-->
    <div class="overlay">
      <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- end loading -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 text-center esconde" id="boxPainelSituacaoAtualHidrico">

      <div class="box box-primary esconde" id="boxGraficoAtualHidricoSensor1">
        <input type="text" class="knob" value="30" data-width="90" data-height="90" id="inputKnobHidricoSensor1" data-readOnly="true">
        <div class="knob-label" id="labelSituacaoAtualHidricoSensor1"></div>
        <div class="box box-primary bg-aqua-active color-palette">
            <div id="mediaRegistradaHidricoSensor1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="box box-primary esconde" id="boxGraficoAtualHidricoSensor2">      
        <input type="text" class="knob" value="30" data-width="90" data-height="90" id="inputKnobHidricoSensor2" data-readOnly="true">
        <div class="knob-label" id="labelSituacaoAtualHidricoaSensor2"></div>
        <div class="box box-primary bg-aqua-active color-palette">
            <div id="mediaRegistradaHidricoSensor2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>


  <div class="col-md-8">
  <!-- AREA CHART -->
  <div class="box box-primary esconde" id="boxGraficoHidrico">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
      <h3 class="box-title">Histórico de Nivel de Reservatórios</h3>

      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="chart" id="areaChartContainer">
        <canvas id="areaChart" style="height:310px"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
  </div>


</div>
</div>

<!-- Gráficos de temperatura -->
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-2 text-center" id="boxPainelSituacaoAtualTemperatura">

      <div class="box box-danger esconde" id="boxGraficoAtualTemperaturaSensor1">
        <input type="text" class="knob" value="30" data-width="90" data-height="90" id="inputKnobTemperaturaSensor1" data-readOnly="true">
        <div class="knob-label" id="labelSituacaoAtualTemperaturaSensor1"></div>
        <div class="box box-danger bg-red color-palette">
            <div id="mediaRegistradaTemperaturaSensor1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="box box-danger esconde" id="boxGraficoAtualTemperaturaSensor2">      
        <input type="text" class="knob" value="30" data-width="90" data-height="90" id="inputKnobTemperaturaSensor2" data-readOnly="true">
        <div class="knob-label" id="labelSituacaoAtualTemperaturaSensor2"></div>
        <div class="box box-danger bg-red color-palette">
            <div id="mediaRegistradaTemperaturaSensor2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

<div class="col-md-8">

   <!-- FLOT CHART -->
  <div class="box box-danger esconde" id="boxGraficoTemperatura">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
            <h3 class="box-title">Histórico de Temperatura das Bombas</h3>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div id="line-chart" style="height: 300px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body-->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="saida"></div>
</section>



<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- ChartJS 1.0.1 Hídrico-->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- date-range-picker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<!-- Flot graph (Temperatura) -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>


<!-- Utilitários -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/js/utilitarios.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/js/graph/graficos.js"></script>

<script>
/**
Load da Página
*/
$(function () {
    $('#diaPesquisa').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy" ,
        language: "pt-BR",
        autoclose:true
    });


 $.get('/sistema/public/dashload', function(dataLoad){
   var hasError = showLoadError(dataLoad);
   if(!hasError)
    showFormOptions(dataLoad);
});
});
</script>

<!-- page script -->



  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Versão</b> 1.0.4
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2017 <a href="http://www.sensoragroup.com.br" target='_blank'>Sensora Group</a>.</strong> Todos os direitos reservados
  </footer>

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Create the tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
      <li><a href="#control-sidebar-home-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- Home tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-home-tab">
        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Recent Activity</h3>
        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-birthday-cake bg-red"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Langdon's Birthday</h4>

                <p>Will be 23 on April 24th</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-user bg-yellow"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Frodo Updated His Profile</h4>

                <p>New phone +1(800)555-1234</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-envelope-o bg-light-blue"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Nora Joined Mailing List</h4>

                <p>nora@example.com</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-file-code-o bg-green"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Cron Job 254 Executed</h4>

                <p>Execution time 5 seconds</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Tasks Progress</h3>
        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Custom Template Design
                <span class="label label-danger pull-right">70%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Update Resume
                <span class="label label-success pull-right">95%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 95%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Laravel Integration
                <span class="label label-warning pull-right">50%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 50%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Back End Framework
                <span class="label label-primary pull-right">68%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" style="width: 68%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Stats tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab">Stats Tab Content</div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Settings tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
        <form method="post">
          <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Report panel usage
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>

            <p>
              Some information about this general settings option
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Allow mail redirect
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>

            <p>
              Other sets of options are available
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Expose author name in posts
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>

            <p>
              Allow the user to show his name in blog posts
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Chat Settings</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Show me as online
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Turn off notifications
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right">
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Delete chat history
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-red pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
    </div>
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
       immediately after the control sidebar -->
  <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/js/dropdown.js"></script>


<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<!-- <script src="plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>


<!-- Sparkline 
<script src="plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>

<!-- jvectormap 
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Knob Chart 
<script src="plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>

<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<!-- datepicker 
<script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap datepicker -->

<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>


<!-- Slimscroll 
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>


<!-- FastClick 
<script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>


<!-- AdminLTE App 
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) 
<script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes 
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/dist/js/demo.js"></script>



<!-- <script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/js/app.js"></script>
 -->


<script>
  $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $(".select2").select2();

    //Datemask dd/mm/yyyy
    $("#datemask").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});
    //Datemask2 mm/dd/yyyy
    $("#datemask2").inputmask("mm/dd/yyyy", {"placeholder": "mm/dd/yyyy"});
    //Money Euro
    $("[data-mask]").inputmask();

    //Date range picker
    $('#reservation').daterangepicker();
    //Date range picker with time picker
    $('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'});
    //Date range as a button
    $('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(
        {
          ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
          },
          startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
          endDate: moment()
        },
        function (start, end) {
          $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        }
    );

    //Date picker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      autoclose: true
    });

    //iCheck for checkbox and radio inputs
    $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue'
    });
    //Red color scheme for iCheck
    $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal-red, input[type="radio"].minimal-red').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-red',
      radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-red'
    });
    //Flat red color scheme for iCheck
    $('input[type="checkbox"].flat-red, input[type="radio"].flat-red').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
      radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'
    });

    //Colorpicker
    $(".my-colorpicker1").colorpicker();
    //color picker with addon
    $(".my-colorpicker2").colorpicker();

    //Timepicker
    $(".timepicker").timepicker({
      showInputs: false
    });
  });
</script>




</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML output you've got jQuery sourced three times on that page. First time it's sourced right before you source Flot.

```
<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- ChartJS 1.0.1 Hídrico-->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- date-range-picker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<!-- Flot graph (Temperatura) -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
```

Then later down the page you source it again here:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/js/dropdown.js"></script>
```

Then almost immediately after you do it again here:

```
<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/sistema/public/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

Aside from loading jQuery too many times, the issue you're seeing is the first jQuery is loaded and then you source Flot which binds to that instance of jQuery. Once the next sourced instance of jQuery happens that association disappears.

Take time to assure you're sourcing jQuery once at the beginning of your sourced scripts and then source everything that depends on jQuery.